Unable to Test Flutter Chromecast Implementation with Android Studio TV Emulators
I have implemented Chromecast functionality in my Flutter application, but I am facing challenges testing it with the TV emulators available in Android Studio. I need to ensure that the Chromecast integration works correctly, but the emulators do not seem to recognize the Chromecast device.
Issues I am encountering:

The Android Studio TV emulators are unable to detect any Chromecast devices.

I do not have access to a physical Chromecast device, making it difficult for me to test my application effectively.


I would greatly appreciate any suggestions or alternative methods to test my Chromecast implementation without a physical device.
Thank you for your assistance!
What I tried:
I set up a Flutter application with Chromecast integration and attempted to run it on the Android Studio TV emulators. I specifically tried to connect the emulator to the Chromecast service using the standard APIs provided by the Flutter Chromecast package.
What I expected:
I expected the emulator to recognize any available Chromecast devices on the network and allow me to cast media from my Flutter application to the Chromecast device seamlessly.
What actually resulted:
However, the emulator did not detect any Chromecast devices, and I was unable to test the casting functionality. This led to a lack of confidence in the implementation, as I couldn't verify if it was functioning correctly without a physical Chromecast device.

Similar to: Will there be Chromecast Receiver Emulator or an alternate app that acts as a receiver for development? but personally a physical device would be best.

I would like to use Android TV itself in the emulator.
